# Take photo with metadata

Tags: android, camera, metadata-editor

I want to manage my receipts. I tried several apps made for that purpose, but results were not so good as I expected (eg. no way to share, weird storage format). So now my idea is that I just want to have a collection of photos (of my receipts) together with my some metadata (always the same set). Therefore I need an application that:

1. Is able to take a photo (preferably using external app).
2. Allow me to add some metadata according to predefined template (date of purchase, warranty length, value, etc.). Preferably while still displaying image on screen.
3. Save to predefined folder.

I don't need any reporting and fancy features. Some photo preprocessing of image receipt would be a nice addition (eg. take receipt out of background, find out product name and value, purchase date), but it is certainly not necessary. Also editing of metadata is not a must - as long as it can be done in any other application.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Mind to let us know what OS this should be for, and how much you'd be willing to spent if it comes to paid solutions? If it's e.g. for Android, there are [several apps specialized on this](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_receipts).

Comment: Added android tag. I had a look at some of the apps listed, but they are either bloated with things like expense reports and statistics (Smart Receipts) or they cannot share data between accounts and it is not clear where data is stored (MrReceipt).

Comment: Yeah, that's the trouble – and the reason why I didn't put a recommendation straight. Please `@ping` me if you find something suitable, so I can update my list and place a good candidate!

Comment: Can I suggest taking a look at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/ as I think that you will find it very relevant to what you are doing (even if it doesn't do anything about metadata).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any android camera app and use [A Photo Manager-s Autoprocessing mode](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/AutoProcessing) to automatically assign Tags/Title/Description/gps to photo-s metadata while copying/moving the photos.

Note: I am the author of "A Photo Manager".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image EXIF Tags using [FastPhotoTagger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.fastphototagger&hl=en_GB) which is a free app.

- Allows you to see and edit EXIF data
- You can see the image while modifying the data
- You can use abbreviations for your commonly used tags
- Free, Open Source (GPL), No Adverts
- Allows you to perform some file system operations (depending on where the files are stored).
- Supports most common file formats
- Supports all/most EXIF fields
- Search on metadata
- Select multiple files to apply the same tag*(s)* to all.
- View the metadata for multiple files side by side
- For advanced users there is direct access to the ExifTool if needed

**N.B.** Can I suggest taking a look at [this PyImageSearch blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) item as I think that you will find it very relevant to what you are doing *(even if it doesn't do anything about metadata)* and you could expand on what it does to also make use of the metadata to aid in the post processing of your receipts on Windows/Mac/Linux.

[image]
[image]
[image]